# How to cover for loop in test class

Tags: unit-test

I have written testmethod for this code but i am not able to cover for loop.

```
 public static Boolean gettest(String accountId)
     {   
        Boolean claim;
        System.debug('Account id==>'+ accountId);
        Account AccountRec=[Select Id,Name,(Select Id,RecordType.Name from Cases where (Status != 'Closed' AND Status !='Closed-Duplicate' AND Status !='Cancelled')) from Account where Id=:accountId];
        if(AccountRec.cases.size()>0)
        {
            for(Case cse:AccountRec.cases)
            {

                if(cse.RecordType.Name =='test Claim')
                {
                    claim = true;
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            claim = false;
        }
        return claim;
    }
```

My test code is:

```
Case cs = new Case();
       Id caseRecTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('test Claim').getRecordTypeId();    
       cs.Status ='In Progress';
       cs.Priority='Medium'; 
       cs.Origin = 'Email';
       cs.Account= testAccount; 
       cs.Account__c   = testAccount.id;
       cs.reason__c='test';
       cs.RecordTypeId = caseRecTypeId; 
       insert cs; 

       Test.getCall(testAccount.id);   
    }
```

I am not able to cover below parts. please help.

```
        for(Case cse:AccountRec.cases)
        {

            if(cse.RecordType.Name =='test Claim')
            {
                claim = true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please do not remove so much code that your post loses all context.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is basically completely overkill. Your method could have been written as:

```
 public static Boolean getTest(Id accountId) {
   return 1 == [SELECT COUNT() FROM Case WHERE IsClosed = FALSE AND
                AccountId = :accountId AND RecordType.Name = 'test claim'
                LIMIT 1];
 }
```

Note that `test claim` is not the same as `testclaim`, so make sure your record type name is correct.

Also, generally speaking, you should always assign values to an ID field:

```
   cs.Account= testAccount;
```

Should be:

```
   cs.AccountId = testAccount.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your test class code.

```
   Id caseRecTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('testClaim').getRecordTypeId();
```

Should be

```
   Id caseRecTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('test Claim').getRecordTypeId();
```

You havent added space in **test claim.**

Comment: Hi Pranay, that is not issue.

Comment: Am sorry , I answered according to the Initial post you made, Typo was the main issue in that.

Comment: Actually i forgot to give space in editor.